# finding an element in a multimap ONLY with its value c++

Tags: c++, find, multimap

First of all sorry if I am asking stupid questions, but I am a beginer in c++.

I am writing a system that represents a library and there is a member function of my Library class that is supposed to allow us to remove a book. Now, if the book is loaned by a user, means there is an element in my `_usersLoaningMultimap` (`multimap<UserId,LoanInfo>`). How can I find the LoanInfo that I want without knowing the key (UserId)?

```
bool Library::removeBook(const BookId& bookId){
//how to find my book in my library without knowing who loaned it.
```

}

Just to make it clearer, my class Library is like that:

```
class Library {
public:
Library();
void addUser(const UserId&, const string&);
Optional<string>& getUserInfo(const UserId& userId);
void addBook(const BookId& bookId, const string& description);
Optional<string>& getBookInfo(const BookId& bookId);
bool returnBook(const UserId& userId, const BookId& bookId);
void loanBook(const UserId& userId,LoanInfo& loan);
bool removeUser(const UserId& userId);
void getLoansSortedByDate(const UserId,std::vector<LoanInfo>& loanVector);

~Library() {}
private:
map<BookId, string> _bookMap;
map<UserId, string> _userMap;
multimap<UserId, LoanInfo> _usersLoaningMultimap;

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to iterate through the whole map like this :

```
for(multimap<userId,LoanInfo>::iterator it = _usersLoaningMultimap.begin(); it != _usersLoaningMultimap.end(); it++){
    //it->first retrieves key and it->second retrieves value 
    if(it->second == loan_info_you_are_searching){
         //do whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: I must start iterator with `_usersLoaningMultimap.begin()`. I will edit on answer.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) doesn't provide any method for value lookup. Your only choice is to read through the multimap looking for a particular value.

You can use [std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) for that purpose :

```
using const_ref = std::multimap<UserId, LoanInfo>::const_reference;
std::find_if(_usersLoaningMultimap.begin(), _usersLoaningMultimap.end(),
    [&](const_ref a) -> bool {
        return a.second == your_loan_info;
    });
```

If you don't like the syntax, you can also make your own function :

```
using Map = std::multimap<UserId, LoanInfo>;
auto findLoanInfo(const Map& map, const LoanInfo& info) -> Map::iterator {
    for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it) {
        if (it->second == info) {
            return it;
        }
    }

    return map.end();
}
```

Comment: @adlsc I messed up the first edit, you might want to read the answer again. If you don't understand something, point it out precisely.